# can i save text boxes / drop down menu chosen values in html page in order to load it again?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got an html that includes a table with drop-down menus and text boxes. the users write their input in the text boxes and choose values in the drop-down menus. after clicking on 'save' button I want to save the data so if another user will open the page he will see the most updated version.
is it possible with JS / HTML ?

Comment: You can use **LocalStorage** to store your data on the browser and then you can get the data again from the localStorage to show other user.

Comment: you can maintain data.json file having form data object  and keep adding,updating or deleting.so anybody from anywhere accessing that page can load latest data.

Answer (score 0):

Here two options are available. `Local Storage` and `Session Storage`. As per your context you need to go with `Local Storage` it seems.

The major difference between `local storage` and `session storage` is data persistence. This means when we use `localStorage`, data is present and available across various sessions (across multiple windows) i.e. you can close your browser and come later and any data that has been stored in `localStorage` will be available to you. While in `Session Storage` the data is used only on one browser window which means as soon as we close our window our session keys are destroyed and will not be accessible across sessions.